# numpy array to a file, np.savetxt

Tags: python, numpy

What is the best way to save more than one numpy array to a file, when I use np.savetxt(´file.txt´, (arr1,arr2,arr3))
The arrays are saved column-wise and not row-wise, making it difficult to import into excel.
How to a save the array in a more standard way?

Thanks

Comment: It depends on array dimensions.  you can try to group them first :   arr=np.vstack((arr1,arr2,arr3)) and then save it.

Answer (score 4):

I have almost direct answer to this is outlined here http://rinocloud.github.io/rinocloud-tutorials/saving-data-with-numpy

Using vstack

### Saving multiple arrays from numpy with vstack

Say we have a numpy array we want to save to a file

```
x = np.random.random_integers(0, 10, size=10)
np.savetxt('test.txt', x)
```

It will give a file with the following content

```
0.0e+00
8.0e+00
7.0e+00
6.0e+00
1.0e+01
7.0e+00
9.0e+00
9.0e+00
0.0e+00
3.0e+00
```

This is great, the column based representation means that its easy to import into csv compatible programs
like excel, LabView, Matlab and Origin.

But what happens when we want to save two or more arrays together and make sure the file is still easily importable
into different programs.

If we just use

```
x = np.random.random_integers(0, 10, size=10)
y = np.random.random_integers(0, 10, size=10)
z = np.random.random_integers(0, 10, size=10)

np.savetxt('test.txt', (x, y, z))
```

we get

```
9.0e+00 9.0e+00 4.0e+00 2.0e+00 0.0e+00 8.0e+00 1.0e+01 2.0e+00 1.0e+00 9.0e+00
2.0e+00 3.0e+00 1.0e+00 9.0e+00 2.0e+00 5.0e+00 1.0e+01 2.0e+00 8.0e+00 3.0e+00
9.0e+00 8.0e+00 2.0e+00 7.0e+00 9.0e+00 0.0e+00 6.0e+00 0.0e+00 2.0e+00 3.0e+00
```

So instead lets use [numpy vstack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html).

```
x = np.random.random_integers(0, 10, size=10)
y = np.random.random_integers(0, 10, size=10)
z = np.random.random_integers(0, 10, size=10)

np.savetxt('test.txt', np.vstack((x, y, z)).T)
```

This gives us a `test.txt` with

```
9.0e+00 2.0e+00 9.0e+00
9.0e+00 3.0e+00 8.0e+00
4.0e+00 1.0e+00 2.0e+00
2.0e+00 9.0e+00 7.0e+00
0.0e+00 2.0e+00 9.0e+00
8.0e+00 5.0e+00 0.0e+00
1.0e+01 1.0e+01 6.0e+00
2.0e+00 2.0e+00 0.0e+00
1.0e+00 8.0e+00 2.0e+00
9.0e+00 3.0e+00 3.0e+00
```

Which is much more portable, and can be imported into programs like excel easily.

To read the file again using numpy into the arrays use

```
x, y, z = np.loadtxt('test.txt').T
```

This is a quick and easy way to get arrays in and out of files from numpy. It keeps the files portable for use with other programs.