# Saving a row-wise txt with numpy with a pre-defined delimiter

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have two `numpy` arrays `x` and `y` and I want to save them in a `txt` with a tab as a delimiter (`\t`) and their appropriate type (`x` is a `float` and `y` is a `integer`) and a certain format. For example:

```
import numpy as np
x=np.random.uniform(0.1,10.,4)
y=np.random.randint(10,size=4)
```

If I simply use `np.savetxt('name.txt',(x,y))`, this is what I get:

```
6.111548206503401026e+00 4.208270401300298058e-01 5.914485954766230957e-01 6.652272388676337966e-01
6.027109785846696433e+00 1.024051075089774443e+01 3.358386699980072621e+01 7.652668778594046151e-01
```

But what I want is a row-wise `txt` file, so I followed this solution: 
[numpy array to a file, np.savetxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34768082/numpy-array-to-a-file-np-savetxt)

and bu using
`np.savetxt('name.txt',np.vstack((x,y)).T,delimiter='\t')` I get:

```
2.640596763338360020e+00    4.000000000000000000e+00
8.693117057064670306e+00    4.000000000000000000e+00
3.891035166453641558e+00    6.000000000000000000e+00
9.044178202861068883e+00    2.000000000000000000e+00
```

Until here it is ok, but as I mentioned, I want the output to have the appropriate data type and some formatting, so I tried `np.savetxt('name.txt',np.vstack((x,y)).T,fmt=('%7.2f,%5i'),delimiter='\
    ...: t')`, and what I get is:

```
   2.64,    4
   8.69,    4
   3.89,    6
   9.04,    2
```

which does have the appropriate format and data type, but which adds a `,` after the columns. Does anyone knows how to get rid of this `,` printed after the column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma is in your `fmt` string. Replace it with `fmt='%7.2f %5i'`, like so:

```
np.savetxt('name.txt',np.vstack((x,y)).T,fmt='%7.2f %5i')
```

Note the tab delimiter (`delimiter='\t'`) is not necessary as `np.vstack((x,y)).T` fills only one column. If you want a tab between the values, change the format string to `fmt='%7.2f \t%5i'` or alternatively:

```
np.savetxt('name.txt',np.vstack((x,y)).T,fmt=('%7.2f', '%5i'), delimiter='\t')
```